# Apply compiler switches to certain files

Tags: premake

I want to specify compiler switches for a certain directory only in premake.
Now AFAIR, I think I should have to use `buildoption` for the switches.

So I would await:

```
configuration    { "vs2010" }
    files        { "mysubdir/**" }
    buildoption  { "/wd4244" }
```

Sadly this does not seem to work. Is this even possible with premake?

Comment: According to [this](http://industriousone.com/configuration) per-file configurations are currently only implemented for `buildaction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [the latest development version of Premake](https://github.com/premake/premake-core), you can do it like this:

```
filter { "files:mysubdir/**" }
    buildoptions { "/wd4244" }
```

I don't recall if per-file build options were supported in Premake 4.x, but if so it would work like this:

```
configuration { "mysubdir/**" }
    buildoptions { "/wd4244" }
```

Comment: We use an ancient version of premake, so no luck there. The latter does not seem to work either. For us, we do apply this by other means.

Comment: The link to the `latest development version of Premake` is dead because it got absorbed into the core, sometime in 2016: https://github.com/premake/premake-core